# QNAP Jenkins in docker deploy to /share/Web with git and rsync

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I have in Container Station a container running Jenkins.

My volumes look like this:

```
volumes:
      - /share/Container/jenkins_website:/var/jenkins_home
      - /share/Web/website-testing:/var/jenkins_home/deploy/website-testing
```

And this is my job's config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@5.2.1">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <refspec>+refs/tags/testing-*:refs/remotes/tags/testing-*</refspec>
        <url>http://192.168.1.89/Bonobo.Git.Server/Website.git</url>
        <credentialsId>4c33a128-87aa-4eb8-85fc-ee624029a69a</credentialsId>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>:^tags/testing-\w+?-\d{8}-rc\d+?$</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="empty-list"/>
    <extensions>
      <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.RelativeTargetDirectory>
        <relativeTargetDir>website-testing</relativeTargetDir>
      </hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.RelativeTargetDirectory>
    </extensions>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <authToken>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</authToken>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

And finally I have this command to run on "Build Steps"

`rsync --dry-run -rc -vi --delete $WORKSPACE/website-testing/htdocs/ $JENKINS_HOME/deploy/website-testing/htdocs`

Ideally I just want to update the files changed, without caring about ownership, permissions and timestamps.

If that's difficult I'd like to just change ownership and permissions to something that makes sense after `rsync` has finished.

I've tried:
`rsync --dry-run -avi --delete`

Output:

```
.d..tp.g... ./
>f.stp.g... cache.manifest
>f..tp.g... document.php
>f.stp.g... error_log
>f..tp.g... favicon.ico
>f..tp.g... filefunc.inc.php
>f..tp.g... index.php
>f.stp.g... main.inc.php
>f..tp.g... master.inc.php
>f..tp.g... opcachepreload.php
>f..tp.g... robots.txt
>f..tp.g... security.txt
....
....
....
....
```

(Pretty much all files)

These files' contents should be identical.

I think `rsync --dry-run -rc -vi --delete` would work but it's a bit slow because it has to checksum all files.

Do I just rsync while updating mod-time once and then run `-avi`.

Does git checkout mess with ownership/timestamps of files? Will I run into any problems with it?

Thank you.

I've been doing WinMerge local to testing until now, so any alternative is an upgrade to me.

Edit: It seems I also may have problems with white spaces, some files I've never touched in my life show no difference when using `diff file_A file_B -white`